# Checking a password meets PAM rules before trying to change password?

Tags: java, pam

I'm working on a Java web application which manages several hosts, one of the things I need to do is setup and configure a host which has a known default configuration. The host is a custom Linux based on RHEL.

I need to be to change the password for the root user based on user input in the web app, this is part of a long workflow so our application pre-validates all the user input.

Currently we have code that checks against the equivalent of what the PAM rules should be however some passwords are being rejected (We thing it's because the PAM config has some dictionary word look up restrictions).

I have the facility to upload and run a Bash or Python script on the host, but I can't install any libraries or software on it.

Is there a way to check that a given password meets all the PAM rules on the host without first trying to change the password?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to predict the future. You can't. *Either* you use exactly the same rules that PAM does, in which case you're merely repeating work, *or* you don't, in which case you're just wasting time.

The correct action in all these circumstances is to attempt the actual action and deal with the failure after it occurs. Not before.

Comment: I'm looking for an interim fix that allows me to check a password against the current PAM rules with the absolute knowledge that the rules are not going to change between the password being checked and the password being set. My UI team don't have the bandwidth to implement a failover to ask the user for a different password just now so I'm trying to work around technical debt for a p1 issue.